# How can I activate a function when I start typing? (Python)

Tags: python

I have written a program which clocks how fast I write some text to improve my touch typing speed.

The thing is that I don't like that I have to press Enter to start the program and THEN start writing. I would like to start the program and let the timer set off exactly when I have pressed the first key.

I was thinking if it would be possible to use the first character of the text I should write instead of Enter to finish an input. If so, I could solve the problem.

I was wondering if anyone has some kind of advice on how I could do this or just solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search turned up the [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) module for me, it looks like something that you could easily build into what you are talking about.